# À la recherche d'une expression pour « a hill to die on »

Tags: expressions, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

Pendant une conversation hier, je me suis rendu compte que je ne sais pas comment exprimer cette idée d'une manière idiomatique. Bien évidemment, je peux expliquer ainsi

> C'est-à-dire, il s'agit d'une idée à laquelle tu tiens vraiment, à tel point qu'il n'y a presque rien qui peut changer ton avis. Il y a aussi, parfois, une insinuation que cette idée n'est pas quelque chose avec lequel tout le monde serait d'accord.

Mais cela rompt le rythme d'une conversation et j'aurais largement préféré dire tout simplement « so you're willing to die on this hill ? »

Donc, existe-t-il une expression qui exprime à peu près la même chose ? J'ai cherché vite fait sur WordReference mais je n'ai rien trouvé qui me convienne.

Comment: https://geudensherman.wordpress.com/gram/phrase/modes-relative/

Answer (score 5):

> Tu y tiens [*mordicus*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mordicus).

Certainement utile pour l'idée de laquelle *on ne [démord](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/d%C3%A9mordre) pas* (*démordre* est aussi utile en soi). Mais ça ne permet pas de traduire tous les [contextes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Citations:hill_to_die_on#English) où l'expression pourrait être utilisée ; ça devra être du cas par cas. Parfois ça pourrait être *la chose pour laquelle on se bat jusqu'au bout*, [coûte que coûte](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/co%C3%BBte_que_co%C3%BBte) ou dont on fait un [*sine qua non*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sine_qua_non) (substantivement), *une question de principe* etc. Dans mon sociolecte (au Québec) on utilise parfois le verbe et l'adjectif [*boquer/boqué(e)* : « tu vas resté boqué(e) là-dessus »](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/boquer) dans le sens de tenir tête, résister. D'ailleurs je peux imaginer [*tenir tête*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tenir_t%C3%AAte) [*contre vents et marées*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/contre_vents_et_mar%C3%A9es), mais c'est davantage « ne pas céder » avec « obstinément malgré les difficultés » (Wiktionnaire). Je ne sais pas si tu avais déjà rejeté ces suggestions que l'on trouve en partie sur [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hill-to-die-on.3404748/)...

Answer (score 2):

Donné un contexte de risque de perte de possessions matérielles, une traduction spécifique peut être utilisée.

> ([usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/lexies?lt=laisser)) quitte à y laisser sa dernière chemise, prêt à y laisser sa dernière chemise

([L'habitat de l'homme - 1976](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_habitat_de_l_homme/Z7BHAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22quitte+%C3%A0+y+perdre+sa%22&dq=%22quitte+%C3%A0+y+perdre+sa%22&printsec=frontcover)) On a donc acheté à prix d'or , quitte à y perdre sa chemise

([Le Sang de ma Langue - 2017](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Sang_de_ma_Langue/Nn40DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quitte+%C3%A0+y+perdre+sa%22&pg=PA12&printsec=frontcover))  Quitte à y perdre sa dernière chemise, S'y perdre a sa guise ! Se fermer au monde pour conquérir sa nuit. Etre méchant à satiété. Être lourd comme la gaité en berne.

- They're willing to die on a hill to make that business prosperous again.
  1- *Ils sont prêt à y laisser leur dernière chemise, pourvu qu'ils rendent cette affaire rentable de nouveau.*
  2- *Ils veulent rendre cette affaire rentable de nouveau quitte à y laisser leur dernière chemise.*

Il existe l'expression très concise « *à tout prix* », qui est applicable dans une variété de contextes.

([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prix))  À tout prix. Quel que soit le prix. Au fig. Coûte que coûte, à toute force.

- So you are ready to die on a hill to get that motorcycle?
  *Alors tu veux cette moto à tout prix ?*

Une expression qui finalement serait la plus exacte, bien que l'idée ne soit pas tout à fait aussi extrême, « [*vivre un calvaire*](http://col58-aumeuniermichot.ac-dijon.fr/IMG/pdf/Vivre_un_calvaire.pdf) » permet les traductions de l'expression anglaise en isolation.

([On Pastoring: A Short Guide to Living, Leading, and ... - 2016](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/On_Pastoring/L9FNCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22die+on+a+hill%22&pg=PT81&printsec=frontcover))  Knowing when to die on a hill and when to stay in the valley.
*Savoir quand vivre un calvaire et quand se ménager.*

- so you're willing to die on this hill ?
  *Alors vous êtes décidé à vivre un calvaire ?*

Answer (score 1):

**Mettre sa main au feu**

[Tu veux mettre la main au feu ?](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/mettre-sa-main-au-feu)

(Par hyperbole) Assurer que la chose est ainsi, en répondre à ses risques et périls.

> Vient de l’épreuve du feu (généralement un fer rouge) du jugement de
> Dieu (ordalie). Cela consistait à porter une barre de fer rougie sur
> neuf pas (ou marcher sur des socs de charrue chauffés à blanc). La
> main était par la suite bandée dans un sac de cuir scellé par le juge.
> Pour savoir si l'accusé était coupable ou innocent, on regardait trois
> jours plus tard l'évolution de la plaie. Si la plaie était « belle »,
> donc bien cicatrisée, cela prouvait l'innocence. Une vilaine plaie
> prouvait la culpabilité, la sentence étant proportionnelle à son état.

Comment: Interesting, but "mettre sa main au feu" carries the idea of a "sure bet", not the idea of a "fight to the death".

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas d'équivalent exact, tout dépend du contexte

S'il s'agit d'une exclamation :

> Tu y tiens vraiment !

> Tu t'entêtes là-dessus !

Une interrogation :

> Jusqu'où es-tu prêt(e) à aller pour défendre cela ?

> Es-tu sûr(e) de vouloir aller aussi loin pour défendre cela ?

La négative est plus courante à mon avis

> *It's not a hill I want to die on*
>
> Je ne vais pas me battre pour cela